# cloud ready software

Tags: java, cloud, amazon-cloudfront, cloud-hosting

I have my own application server ( like oracle weblogic ) which handles HTTP request.

Now what changes required in my software to make it cloud ready.I was searching on the net and got one multi tenency documents.

what are other aspects in which i need to look into.

Comment: Would you be able to provide some more information if the answer below isn't appropriate :)

Answer (score 0):

None, EC2 should act like any other web server.  You still have the added overhead of maintaining the open ports and the like through Amazon's interface as well as on the server itself, but in terms of actually running a web server, it should be exactly the same.

In terms of multi-tenancy, again this is just down to your database architecture which RDS should take care of (if you have a tenancy key).